# Backbone.js comparator function, how can I implement descending order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js

I have a simple comparator function on a Backbone.js collection.

```
comparator: function (topic) {
        return topic.get('lastReply');
    },
```

This is the correct field to sort.  It's a date field. I would like it to be sorted in desc order.  Is there an easy way to reverse the order? Perhaps I should ditch this function and just sort the collection in prior to rendering it? Any ideas or tips are of course appreciated. Thanks all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it's a JavaScript "Date" field, you could do this:

```
 comparator: function(topic) {
   return - topic.get('lastReply').getTime();
 }
```

That'd return the negative of the timestamp, so that newer timestamps (bigger numbers) would come before older ones.

For a string-valued field this'd be tricky; you'd need to do something like "invert" the string character by character, or something.

Comment: this works fine in the scenario where you want to display Active users (status = 1) first and Inactive users (status = 0) separately after sorting.